# How does this test for debugger

Tags: assembly, malware, anti-debugging

While reading a book it mentioned that the following code is usually used to as an antidebugger

```
mov     eax,   large fs:18h
mov     eax,   [eax+30h]
movzx   eax,   byte ptr [eax+2]
retn
```

I don't understand what are the keywords `large` , `byte`, `ptr` and `retn`. I am new learner of assembly and its usage in malware.

Comment: i dont undestand what is the function of "large , byte, prt, retn" - i'm afraid you still have a lot more to learn before you'd understand any answer to your question.

Comment: From your original post (which was edited out by @perror) - "I was supposed to accept the code as it is without further understanding". If that's indeed the case, then you should throw out that book and get a better one.

Comment: Your book, or your copied code, contains typos. `[eax 30h]` is not valid assembler.

Comment: I tried to make this question a bit better (a lot of work... indeed). Even if it was extremely badly asked, I think that this anti-debug trick (and the answer of broadway) worth to be mentioned. I propose to reopen the question now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect, but the code is basically what IsDebuggerPresent does.

1. Get a pointer to the [TEB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_Environment_Block) (located at fs:18h)
2. Get a pointer to the [PEB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Environment_Block) (located at teb+30h)
3. Check the BeingDebugged flag (located at peb+2)

The syntax should be something like:

```
mov     eax, large fs:18h
mov     eax, [eax+30h]
movzx   eax, byte ptr [eax+2]
```

If you don't understand assembler syntax, though, you're generally going to have a bad time when analyzing malware.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/hpeYIMn.jpg